# How to display results from a result set in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have the following codes, I added the debug and this is the data that I am able to retrieve from the database. I wish to display the `['User']['firstName']` and also the `['Passion']['passion_tag']` in the view page, how do I do it? I am facing error such as:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: passion_tag [APP\views\searches\simple_search.ctp, line 127]

```
[5] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 41
                    [password] => 2b4a3cf55ddf9b15e161aeba3540a75ddd6ea872
                    [firstName] => Ming Xin
                    [lastName] => Toh
                    [email] => mingxin@xconnect.com
                    [locale] => eng
                    [displayName] => 
                    [timezone] => 0
                    [gender] => f
                    [dob] => 1989-08-25
                    [aboutme] => 
                    [country_home] => 
                    [country_current] => Singapore
                    [city_current] => 
                    [currentLogin] => 
                    [lastLogin] => 
                    [registeredDate] => 
                    [profileImgBig] => 
                    [image_id] => 
                    [authProvider] => 
                    [token] => 
                    [authId] => 
                )

            [Image] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [name] => 
                    [img_file] => 
                )

            [Passion] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 46
                            [tag] => acting
                            [dateCreated] => 
                            [userDefined] => 1
                            [PassionsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 64
                                    [user_id] => 41
                                    [passion_tag] => acting
                                    [description] => Dont be shy
                                    [datejoined] => 2011-09-07 07:06:54
                                    [type] => professional
                                    [passionImg] => UserPassion/Acting.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 44
                            [tag] => cake baking
                            [dateCreated] => 
                            [userDefined] => 1
                            [PassionsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 62
                                    [user_id] => 41
                                    [passion_tag] => cake baking
                                    [description] => Bakey Bakey
                                    [datejoined] => 2011-09-07 09:04:10
                                    [type] => professional
                                    [passionImg] => UserPassion/Cake Baking.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 42
                            [tag] => hip hop dancing
                            [dateCreated] => 
                            [userDefined] => 1
                            [PassionsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 60
                                    [user_id] => 41
                                    [passion_tag] => hip hop dancing
                                    [description] => Hopping is Good
                                    [datejoined] => 2011-08-23 12:41:55
                                    [type] => personal
                                    [passionImg] => UserPassion/Hiphop-Dance.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 45
                            [tag] => sky diving
                            [dateCreated] => 
                            [userDefined] => 1
                            [PassionsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 63
                                    [user_id] => 41
                                    [passion_tag] => sky diving
                                    [description] => Dont splat the Earth
                                    [datejoined] => 2011-09-07 06:59:43
                                    [type] => personal
                                    [passionImg] => UserPassion/Sky Diving.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 47
                            [tag] => tamil movies
                            [dateCreated] => 
                            [userDefined] => 1
                            [PassionsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 65
                                    [user_id] => 41
                                    [passion_tag] => tamil movies
                                    [description] => Really interesting
                                    [datejoined] => 2011-08-18 16:17:00
                                    [type] => personal
                                    [passionImg] => UserPassion/Tamil Movies.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 43
                            [tag] => teaching
                            [dateCreated] => 
                            [userDefined] => 1
                            [PassionsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 61
                                    [user_id] => 41
                                    [passion_tag] => teaching
                                    [description] => Nothing beats this experience
                                    [datejoined] => 2011-09-09 07:52:12
                                    [type] => professional
                                    [passionImg] => UserPassion/Teaching.jpg
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that this is part of a larger result set retrieved with `$this->Model->find( 'all' )`, so I assume you want to display all names from those results. You have to loop through all results to get individual names. Also, each user has several Passions so again you have to loop through them if you want to display them all.

```
echo 'Our users and their passions are: <ul>';

foreach( $this->data as $user ) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo $user[ 'User' ][ 'firstName' ];
    echo ' who is passionate about: ';
    foreach( $user[ 'Passion' ] as $passion ) {
        echo $passion[ 'PassionsUser' ][ 'passion_tag' ];
        echo ' ';
    }
    echo '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: your codes works,  I already have declared $user as --> foreach ($search_fields as $user) { } How to incorporate your another foreach loop

Comment: your codes also duplicates the username for every passion he has.

Comment: You should use a `$this->Model->find( 'first' )` to get just one record, not them all. The username should not be duplicated in either case.

Answer (score 1):

Passion does not have a `passion_tag` key, `passion_tag` is in `PassionsUser`.

If `$data` is where all the data is stored,

```
echo $data['User']['Passion'][0]['PassionsUser']['passion_tag'];//echo first result
```

If you want to list all, you'll have to iterate through the `PassionUser` array.