# If...Else statement display error logic in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have the following statement to display all my user's passions, it displays all those only with passions, and those without passions, it doesnt show the 'empty' text. Please assist. $cell is a table which I use to append all my data.

```
foreach ($user['Passion'] as $passion) {
    if (empty($passion['PassionsUser']['passion_tag'])) {
        $cell .= 'empty';
    }
        if ($passion['PassionsUser']['type'] == 'personal') {

            $cell .= '[' . $html->link(ucwords($passion['PassionsUser']['passion_tag']), array('controller' => 'passions', 'action' => 'view', $passion['PassionsUser']['passion_tag']), array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'normalTip', 'title' => ucwords($passion['PassionsUser']['type'] . ' passion'))) . ']';
        } elseif ($passion['PassionsUser']['type'] == 'professional') {

            $cell .= '[' . $html->link(ucwords($passion['PassionsUser']['passion_tag']), array('controller' => 'passions', 'action' => 'view', $passion['PassionsUser']['passion_tag']), array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'normalTip', 'title' => ucwords($passion['PassionsUser']['type'] . ' passion'))) . ']';
        }
}
$cells[] = $cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing by your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819178/how-to-display-results-from-a-result-set-in-cakephp), the problem is that if the user doesn't have any passions, `$user[ 'Passion' ]` will be empty so the loop doesn't run at all. Change the code to:

```
if( empty( $user[ 'Passion' ] ) {
    $cell = 'empty';
}
else foreach( $user[ 'Passion' ] as $passion ) {
    ....
}
```